# Why does Visual Studio Code eat space characters after typing a colon?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Very often (but not always) when I'm typing fast* Visual Studio Code ignores space characters following a colon.

For example, I go to type a hash or keyword argument list in Ruby:

```
myhash = {space: :nope}
```

and I get

```
myhash = {space::nope}
```

If I type more deliberately it doesn't happen.

In cases like above, auto-formatting doesn't save me either -- it doesn't parse because :: is ruby's module delimiter.

Is there anything I can do about it? In a project I know well it's literally enough to almost completely offset the productivity advantages of Intellisense.

(*) I'm not particularly fast, but I might get up to the equivalent of around 80wpm for a few lines of code at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! `shift-space` was bound to the `Trigger Suggest`command.